# How do I change this exception?

Tags: nullpointerexception

I'm new to Android Studio.

I'm getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'java.lang.String
> com.alpha1.appname.rider.model.firebase.User.getName()' on a null
> object reference.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I can't seem to fix with the answers on the other similar questions.

\Here is the line that is producing the null pointer exception\

```
private void setDriverData() {
        View navigationHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView tvName = navigationHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.tvDriverName);
        TextView tvStars = navigationHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.tvStars);
        CircleImageView imageAvatar= navigationHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageAvatar);

        tvName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
        if(Common.currentUser.getRates() != null &&
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentUser.getRates()))
            tvStars.setText(Common.currentUser.getRates());



        if(Common.currentUser.getAvatarUrl()!=null &&
                !TextUtils.isEmpty(Common.currentUser.getAvatarUrl()))
            Picasso.get().load(Common.currentUser.getAvatarUrl()).into(imageAvatar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
tvName.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
```

The error message tells you that you cannot call `getName` of `null`. This means that `Common.currentUser` is `null`. Something being `null` means that it is not defined. Referring data members or calling methods of something that does not exist will yield this error. You can fix this issue by properly initializing `Common.currentUser` before that line executes, or defaulting it if it was not defined, like:

```
tvName.setText((Common.currentUser == null) ? "" : Common.currentUser.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this has taken the error from the first line to the second. Is there any chance you are able to show me how to properly structure the code? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @EmileJansen you are welcome! In general we put lines inside the same block vertically aligned, so we see from a glance where a block starts and where it ends. If we break up long logical expressions into several lines for the sake of readability, then we align them vertically, so it will be visually pleasing to look at the code and the code will nonverbally show where an expression/block/method starts and where it ends. Beyond that, structuring the code is a pretty deep topic and if you have confusion about it, I recommend reading a few articles about this topic, they would probably help.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Lajos, is there any chance I could post part of the code I am struggling with so you can give me feedback? I am definitely going to read up on this kind of exception however for now I just need assistance with this one. I will send you a coffee all the way from South Africa☺

Comment: @EmileJansen if you happen to be Zulu, then Sawubona, unmgane. In the other languages I know even less. Now, I'm happy to take a look at your code, but it's outside the scope of SO to ask for code review, so you have three options: 1. You may create a link to your code so that I would take a look. 2. You can create a more focused question about a second problem (my preference). 3. You may ask for code review at a site where that's on-topic. I recommend asking a more focused question here on SO, linking it here in the comments and posting your code for code review at other sources as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Lajos. I am from Cape Town so I speak Afrikaans. "Goeie dag, hoe gaan dit?"

Comment: I will create a second question. The app that I'm busy with is from a repository. I took two apps and merged them into one. Everything works fine except, I have two classes which more or less have the same functionality however, one of the activities seem to be doing to much in the background. I would like to know how to use background threading to make this work. I have read a few articles but I can seem to get it to work on my code

Comment: I'm not fluent in Afrikaans, but Wel dankie. Ek is bly om jou te ontmoet. If two classes look very similar in terms of what they need to do, but they differ in how it is to be done, that sounds very much like interfaces/abstract classes. As about background threading I can recommend this article: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading

Comment: I am so thankful for your advice this far. The app seems to be working fine now. I had to add a nav_graph.xml.

Comment: @EmileJansen I'm happy to help.